# SQLite "PRIMARY KEY must be unique" while concurrent SELECT query

Tags: sqlite

For a web-crawler, I'm running one process with INSERT INTO table into a huge table of 2GB (20 million rows). From time to time, a long-running second process "SELECT * from table" query exports all rows (and converts the data). While the SELECT * is running, the table is of course locked for writing. So the INSERT INTO queries will throw an exception. I catch the exception in the first process and retry every minute until it works.

The strange thing is then after the exception has been caught and the INSERT could theoretically go through, the insert *always* fails with an error "sqlite3.IntegrityError: PRIMARY KEY must be unique". When I check the table, I am sure that none of the primary keys is duplicated. The row has actually not been added at all. When I retry to insert the row manually, it works.

I have the suspicion that some rollback is going on which has to do with the exception. I have no idea what to do (short of creating a signal-file to tell the first process not to touch the database). Any ideas?

Or better, any other ideas on how to properly solve the general problem: One process writes into a table, a second one needs the full table from time to time?

This is in sqlite 3.5.9 with python 2.7. (I would prefer not to upgrade sqlite because of the added dependency.)

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [write-ahead logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), you can have readers and a writer at the same time. (But then you'll have to find time for checkpointing.)